# using custom control inside wpf window

Tags: .net, wpf

I created user controller named MainControl.xaml. Inside my MainWindow.xaml (which is empty, blank) I wan to to insert this MainControl control.

So inside MainWindow loaded event I put

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bc = new Controls.BooksControl();
    bc.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

but nothing happens, obviously I'm missing something

Comment: Can you also post some XAML of your MainWindow?

Comment: main window is empty so it really has nothing inside xaml worth to post, window init. code and empty grid tags.

Comment: In that case you can set the Content of the Grid to `bc`. Although you might want to add your control directly in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to an actual container, in order to show it. For instance a Grid or an StackPanel. If you add a custom [clr-namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Mapping_CLR_Namespaces_to_XML_Namespaces_in_an) you can also add your Control directly from inside your XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You should add your control to the window (set this new control as content of the window):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bc = new Controls.BooksControl();
    bc.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    this.Content = bc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the **MainControl** that you've mentioned is actually the **BooksControl** that is instantiated in your code that you've exposed.

Yes, you've created a new instance in your code-behind but from what I can see you haven't done anything to actually add it to the *layout* (particularly given that you've mentioned that your **MainWindow.xaml** is empty).

Now, I'm also going to assume that when you say "*but nothing happens*" that you mean that your **BooksControl** isn't showing in your **MainWindow** - this is because, as described, you haven't added it to the layout.

The two main ways to do this are in the XAML or in the code behind:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xlmns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls">

    <controls:BooksControl/>

</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bc = new Controls.BooksControl();

    // set the content of the Window to be the BooksControl
    // assuming the BooksControl has default Visibility of Visible
    this.Content = bc;
}
```